# Inserting line break into a rectangle

Tags: terminal-emacs, rectangle

I have a list that looks like

```
1.530 2.895
4.362 50.14
3.14  2.7
```

And I want it to look like

```
1.530
2.895
4.362
50.14
3.14
2.7
```

I suspect there is a clever way to use a rectangle to do this but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Why using a rectangle? This is simply replacing spaces by linebreaks. I.e., `C-M-% [ <SPACE> ] + <RET> C-j <RET>`... The key sequence for `(query-replace-regexp "[ ]+" "\n")`

Comment: @Tobias thanks for that, I just tried it but it did not seem to work. I think it did not register when i hit `C-j` because it simply removed the space

Comment: Sorry, you have to type `C-q C-j` instead of only `C-j`. `C-q` causes literal insertion of the next keystroke.

Comment: I wrote up an answer to mark this question in the question list as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a rectangle for this job.
Just use `(query-replace-regexp "[ ]+" "\n")` to replace the separating spaces by linebreaks.
The corresponding key-sequence is:

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd> `[ ]+` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-q</kbd> <kbd>C-j</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

Meaning:

- <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>  `query-replace-regexp`
- `[ ]+` the regular expression for the strings to be replaced (one or more spaces)
- <kbd>C-q</kbd> next character is inserted literally (`quoted-insert`)
- <kbd>C-j</kbd> newline as the only character of the replacement string

Comment: Note the square brackets are not necessary here: they define a "*character alternative*" with space as the only choice, so you can just use a space followed by a `+`.